# What are the advantages of a nation allowing one of its states to default on its debt?

Tags: international, federalism, finance

Some [Federations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federation) like the U.S.A. do not permit one of their states to file for bankruptcy. My question is why do some countries allow for one of their states to default on its debt, and what might be the advantages of doing so? By state, I mean any organized political community under one government. The question can be extended to cities and municipalities.

Comment: "Wouldn't allowing a state to default not hurt the credit rating of the whole country" that entirely depends on the discretion of the rating agencies and lenders, surely?

Comment: Unless the person who closed this can explain how I can make the question more focused and why it should be more focused since all countries would likely have the same incentives of doing so or not, the question should be reopened.

Comment: The intended level of polity abstraction seems unclear -- that is, the U.S., a federated state, is clearly included in the scope of the question, as presumably would be other federated states like Canada, Russia, India, and Brazil; but it's unclear whether the European Union, or even the UK, would be within the scope of this question.  Please clarify.

Comment: It can be a state or any political entities that's not a country. Isn't that clear from the question itself? Why would you presume someone to make any distinction?

Comment: Vagueness is a property of a text, (*.e.g.* headlines like "Red tape holds up Bridge", or "IRAQI HEAD SOUGHT ARMS"), it's not merely a product of the reader's presumptions.  Please clarify:  would the European Union be within the scope of this question?

Comment: You can interpret it in the most general way possible.

Comment: Yes or no?   Would the European Union be within the scope of this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Wouldn't allowing a state to default not hurt the credit rating of the whole country, isn't it like partially defaulting on its debt and refusing to restructure it?

This is a matter of discretion for the credit rating agencies, and ultimately the public (who choose to buy or not-buy the country's bonds). However, I would not describe it as the federal government "partially defaulting," at least under the US federal system, because:

- Under US law, the federal government has no power to force state governments to pay their debts (except to the extent that the federal courts have jurisdiction over that debt). State governments are separate sovereigns which can make their own decisions about their finances. They are not considered subdivisions of the federal government, and the feds cannot simply order them around.
- The states, in turn, have no power to issue money and are at the *de facto* mercy of the interest rates set by the Federal Reserve. They cannot simply run up a huge amount of debt and then print money to pay for it (unlike the US federal government, which theoretically could do that). They can print *bonds,* of course, but bonds are effectively loans, and must be paid back.
- There is no confusion between state and federal bonds in the US. If you buy bonds issued by the US Treasury, you are buying federal debt. A state going into default would have no effect on those Treasury bonds. Conversely, if you buy state bonds, then the default of a different state (or hypothetically, the federal government) should have no effect on your bonds.

Therefore, if states could and did declare bankruptcy, I would expect the effects on the federal government's credit rating to be muted or nonexistent. Under the right circumstances, state bankruptcy could be an appropriate way of reorganizing a complicated and intractable schedule of debt, and it would also provide a concrete alternative to a federal bailout. Finally, the existence of bankruptcy would place a soft limit on the amount of debt which a state can issue, since creditors would be unwilling to extend an unlimited amount of debt to a sovereign which might declare bankruptcy.

On the other hand, there are policy arguments to disallow state bankruptcy as well:

- Under the no-bankruptcy system, there's no formal, legal mechanism for a state to repudiate any of its (lawfully-created) debt. The last time a state defaulted on debt was during the Great Depression, and this resulted in a messy lawsuit which Arkansas eventually lost. Therefore, investors are more willing to purchase state-issued bonds, which makes it easier for states to raise money by issuing those bonds.

  - You will notice that this is also listed as a pro, above. That's because this could be a pro or a con, depending on your opinion of government spending and the surrounding economic and political circumstances. It's easy for states to raise money, but it's also easy for states to indebt themselves. Those are two sides of the same coin.
- A state which is in financial distress can always raise taxes and cut spending (unlike, say, a corporation, which must remain profitable). Bankruptcy is not, strictly speaking, required to exist.
- States can purchase bonds from other states. One state defaulting on its obligations could harm the finances of other states, and this would magnify the scope of the problem. In extremis, it might even cause other states to default.

Comment: interesting you should suggest that corporation *must remain profitable*, as in some cases it is (fiscally) advantageous to accumulate debt and not be profitable.  Presumably your statement holds over some unspecified timescale…

Comment: @ZeroTheHero: This is a discussion of governments, not the incredibly complex legal morass that is the fiduciary duty between corporations and their shareholders. So yes, it is a simplification, but it's not central to the answer.

Comment: Agreed.  The phraseology did catch my attention.  *morass* is a polite way to describe this.